# Schema JSON codes and their effect on the page speed rank

Tags: javascript, json, seo, schema, structured-data

I searched in many articles but nobody has talked about this stuff.
For example, google suggested JSON-LD for structured data but I wanna know if I add dozens line of JSON codes, does not it affect on my page speed badly?

I mean tools like GTMetrix pay attention to inline JS codes and say:

> > > > > > it is better to minify and load inline codes from a file instead of using them inline.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. Next time, please heed [the warning](https://imgur.com/a/enYwabk) and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.

Answer (score 1):

LD-JSON sits separately to the HTML content on the page, so it’s easy to write and troubleshoot and should not be a problem with performance. You can allways use Google Tag Manager to generate JSON-LD and compare data.